# Always round down to specified number of significant digits in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to alter `signif()` to always round down?

The following are some examples of the expected output using a custom function that rounds down to the specified number of significant digits, as well as the output of `signif()`:

```r
down_signif(117, digits = 2)
# 110

signif(117, digits = 2)
# 120

down_signif(3599, digits = 2)
# 3500

signif(3599, digits = 2)
# 3600

down_signif(7890349, digits = 2)
# 7800000

signif(7890349, digits = 2)
# 7900000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a custom function to do it

```
down_signif <- function(x, digits = 0) {
  m <- 10^(ceiling(log(x, 10)) - digits)
  (x %/% m)*m
}
down_signif(3599, digits = 2)
#> [1] 3500
down_signif(7890349, digits = 2)
#> [1] 7800000
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `signif()` is to use the `DescTools` package, if you want to be able to round down and select the digit (i.e., multiple) to round to. Using your examples above:

```
library(DescTools)

DescTools::RoundTo(117, multiple = 10, FUN = floor)
# 110

DescTools::RoundTo(3599, multiple = 100, FUN = floor)
# 3500

DescTools::RoundTo(7890349, multiple = 100000, FUN = floor)
# 7800000
```

Comment: This is great and offers a lot more flexibility than just rounding down to a specified significant digit. But I was looking for a custom function using base R. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach.

```
down_signif <- function(x, digits = 6) {
  n <- nchar(x)
  as.numeric(substr(x, 1, digits)) * (10^(n - digits))
} 

x <- 67897
down_signif(x, 3)
# [1] 67800
signif(x, 3)
# [1] 67900
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is great but slower than the approach by @pseudospin. Also, this approach does not handle decimals correctly. For example, `down_signif(1.17, digits = 2)` produces 100 whereas I would expect it to produce 1.1. I should have added an example with a decimal to the question. My bad!